# How does Linux disk I/O handles files of different sizes

Tags: linux, io, disk

Does Linux always write a whole number of pages on disk when creating a file, even if the file size is not exactly a whole number of pages?

Comment: A block device always is read and written in units of entire blocks.  This is entirely separate from whether the filesystem can store multiple files in a single block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Linux will write an integer (whole) number of pages on disk, even if the last page is only partially filled.